# Can I initialize something in an iPhone app with a storyboard outside of viewDidLoad?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I have an iPhone application which consists of two View Controllers; a main one, and one with the help screen.  Each one has a button that performs the segue from one to the other.

The problem I have is, when I segue back from the help screen to the main screen, the main view controller's viewDidLoad method gets called, so all of the initialization I did when the app was first started is repeated.  Is there another method in the view controller that gets called just once, where I can do the initialization?

My first thought was, "Have a boolean variable that is initially set to false, then have viewDidLoad test it, and if it is false, do the initialization, then set it to true" - but how do I initialize it to false in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on the .m class file create a bool on `@implementaition`:

```
@implementation yourClass{

    bool initialize = 0;
}
```

and then test it on view did load:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    if(initialize == 0){

    //do everything you need to do

    initialize = 1;

    }
}
```

I think it will work...

Comment: That does work, but now I have a different problem: I have an NSMutableArray of buttons (created dynamically) that is connected to the view through an IBOutletCollection, but when I segue from the help view back to the main view, the buttons no longer exist.  I have a feeling the problem might be that both of the segues are modal, in which case, the question is, what types should they be so the help view won't cause the main view to be overwritten?

Comment: If the views are on a NavigationController the segues have to be Push. If there isn't a NavigationController, you might use Modal.

Comment: Problem solved - I got rid of the Help->Main segue, created a new UIViewController, changed the Help storyboard's class to the class of the new view controller, and created an action for the Help return button that calls dismissModalViewControllerAnimated.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you're doing a "Push" segue (which is the most standard kind of segue one can do in an iOS app), and if you are using a "Push" segue that means you have a navigation controller in your app.

The *best* thing to do here is not to push another "Main" view controller onto the stack of other view controllers (which is why you are seeing "`viewDidLoad`" called each time you push the main view), but instead when you click a "go to main" button in your help screen, *pop* the help screen off and return to the previous one.  The call that would do this is UINavigationController's [`popViewControllerAnimated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popViewControllerAnimated%3a) method.

Doing that means "`viewDidLoad`" on that view controller only gets called once, as the main view gets loaded once.